# Find element by tag inside a variable

Tags: jquery

I just read html using a selector into a variable using

```
var myHtml=$("selector").html();
```

Considering my requirement i have some img tags in that html, i would like to have an access to them.

Is there any function in jquery which lets me search over tags like 'img' inside an variable?

Comment: `var $imgs = $(myHtml).find('img')`

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap it in a jQuery selector and then.. find it:

```
var images = $(myHtml).find('img')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `img` as tagname to get all images. access `html` if image tag wont make much sense.

```
var imgTagCollection = $("img");
```

To get img tags in parent

```
var imgTagCollection = $('parentselector').find("img");
```

Comment: This will find ALL img tags.

Comment: Yes you are right, I mentioned that now check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Got it !

```
$(myHtml).find("img");
```

This gives the listing of all img tags